# In install4j, what does the variable sys.adminRights do? it appears automatically in the response var file

Tags: install4j

When a user runs our installation/upgrade and gets a response var file for the next silent install, we get questions about the properties in that var file.

On of the properties is ***sys.adminRights*** (boolean property)

What does ***sys.adminRights*** do? I can't find any reference for it in the internet / install4j manual. I've also scanned the XML for this attribute, but it's not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This property is set by the "Request privileges" action and indicates if admin privileges were actually obtained.

It is used by the "Require installer privileges" which is added to the uninstaller and possibly to custom installer applications.